# I really don't know how to make collectionViewCell (didSelected) function work properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I'm making a Calendar in Swift 5 and now I'm encountering a problem.
First this is my code:

```
import UIKit

class YearViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var yearName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yearCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        yearName.text = String(CalenderBrain.init().curruntYear)
        yearCollectionView.dataSource = self
        yearCollectionView.delegate = self

        yearCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ReusableYearCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell3")

        if let layout = self.yearCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = -10
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        }

    }

}

extension YearViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell3", for: indexPath) as! ReusableYearCollectionViewCell
        cell.monthName.text = Calendar.current.monthSymbols[indexPath.row]
        if cell.monthName.text == CalenderBrain.init().curruntMonthName(){
            cell.monthName.textColor = .red
            cell.tag = 999
        }
        cell.month = indexPath.row + 1
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return .init(width: 126.3, height:(570-3)/4)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "lastOne") as? ViewController
        vc?.whatIGetFromYearViewController = indexPath.row + 1
        vc?.curruntMonthNameThatIHaveToPut = Calendar.current.monthSymbols[indexPath.row]
        vc?.nextMonthNameThatIHaveToPut = Calendar.current.monthSymbols[indexPath.row + 1]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        print("i'm pressed")
    }
}
```

I want if my cells are clicked then a segue occurs.

And this is an image of my cell. (I make collectionView in collectionViewCell.)

[image]

The problem is the segue only occurs when I click the left part of the label. If I click collectionView in CollectionViewCell then the segue doesn't occur. I think that's because Swift recognizes collectionView in collectionViewCell another CollectionView. So for now, I want to make collectionViewCell clicked and segue occurred regardless of part that I click. Is that possible?

Comment: try set `collectionView.isUserInteractionEnable = false` in collectionViewCell

Comment: wow really thanks a lot!! I make it real

Comment: Good, I post my answer for your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set `collectionView.isUserInteractionEnable = false` in collectionViewCell.

This code will prevent user action onto collectionView in collectionViewCell, just receive didSelectItem action of main collectionView.